# Will a user be notified when I @mention a user while editing a comment?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, comment-replies, comment-edits

For example, if I forget to tag/mention a user in my comment under a Stack Overflow question or answer and I edit the comment to add the tag, will the tagged user then also be notified?